# Python Egg library files referencing other files in same package

Tags: python, python-3.x, databricks, azure-databricks

I have created a python egg file to import a number of my python modules into an Azure databricks cluster.

Some of the files inside the package reference other files inside the same package. Installed locally, everything works great.
When I load the package into Azure databricks and try to use my imported library I get module import errors.

For instance:
module1 looks like this

```
import module2

print('hello, this is module 1')
```

module 2 looks like this

```
print('hello, this is module 2')
```

Notice, module1 imports module2. Module2 import nothing.

I try to import module1 in a workspace py file and when I run that cell, I get an error 'ImportError: No module named 'module2''

From my notebook in databricks, when  I run this code: `from myLibrary import module1`

I get an error: `ImportError: No module named 'module2'`

If I run this: `from myLibrary import module2`

It runs fine

I verified that module2 is included in the egg package.
I uploaded an example of everything minus the Azure databrick, of course, to github
[GitHub Sample](https://github.com/aviatoredb/databricks-test.git)
This is running using the python3 runtime.

Please let me know if there is more information needed to understand the issue and I'll be happy to edit the question and provide it.

Comment: Are you executing a python job rather than a notebook?

Comment: Notebook. In the notebook I execute `from myLibrary import module1' and get the error about module2 not found, when I execute from the same notebook 'from myLibrary import module2` there is no error

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a pythonpath issue (and you are executing as a Python Job). In module1 I would add:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("dbfs:/path/module2.py")
```

This will let all nodes where the file is.

Rather than a py file you can reference a zip file with lots of scripts in - just make sure they are in a flat single folder structure inside the zip.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, I figured this out. Simon, you're answer wasn't right but did up-vote since it got me thinking toward what the real problem was.

There answer is that I brain cramped. 
Referencing the example in my original question I had two python modules in my library, module1 and module2

module2 looks like this:

```
print('Hi, I'm module 2')
```

module1 looks like this:

```
import module2
print('Hi, I'm module 1')
```

If you import module1 into a py file you should see this:

Hi, I'm module 2

Hi, I'm module 1

Now, look back as the code for module1. Specifically, pay attention to my import statement. That's where the problem is. my new py file doesn't have module2 and the python interpreter doesn't default to looking inside the same module apparently (If there is a was to do this, PLEASE let me know. I couldn't find it in the docs)

Anyway, the correct import statement should have been `from MyLibrary import module2`
I confirmed by uploaded to databricks and then applying the same changes to my actual project and all is working.